# Set help balloon text (portlet description) in custom Liferay control panel portlet

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces, liferay-6

I have developed a custom Liferay portlet that appears in the control panel. The existing (Liferay-supplied) portlets all include a nice help balloon and help icon in the Portlet title bar. I'm looking for a way to add that to my custom portlet as well.

Liferay included all the help text identified by portlet name in their Language.properties file. Their control panel portlets seem to use Velocity templates, more or less hard-coding the help feature. I'm using JSF / ICE / LiferayFaces in my portlet and don't see a way of setting these values to get integrated help that looks seamless.

Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a `javax.portlet.description.<your-portlet-name>=My Portlet` to your resource bundle?  The Control Panel help text is derived from the portlet's configured resource bundle and the key must follow that that convention.  Also, `<your-portlet-name>` must match the name you used in the `liferay-portlet.xml` and `portlet.xml` files.

Comment: This looks like the right approach based on the velocity template for control panel portlets. However I've yet to successfully build a resource bundle that results in a valid description returned in PortalImpl. I tried messages.properties and Language_en.properties without success. I'll continue looking. Thanks for the info!